Building a custom Classifier that simulates SVM model
I have the following use of SVM in code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, f1_score

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Separate the features (X) and the target variable (y)
X = data.drop(columns='label')
y = data['label']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Standardize the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Define the parameter grid for a small grid search
param_grid = {
    'C': [0.1, 1, 10],
    'gamma': ['scale', 0.01, 0.1]
}

# Perform a grid search with cross-validation
grid_search = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf'), param_grid, cv=3, scoring='f1_weighted', verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

# Best parameters from grid search
best_params = grid_search.best_params_
print(f'Best parameters: {best_params}\n')

# Train the SVM model with the best parameters
svm_best = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=best_params['C'], gamma=best_params['gamma'])
svm_best.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred_best = svm_best.predict(X_test_scaled)

# Evaluation of the improved model
print("Improved SVM Model Evaluation")
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_best))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_best))
improved_f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred_best, average='weighted')
print(f'Improved Weighted F1 Score: {improved_f1}\n')


As u can see Im using the SVM model straight from sklearn. How can I create a class called "Classifier" which will do the same and get the same results? is it possible?
I tried to create the Class and play with the arguments for each function but always got worse result.
